# Jboss eap7.0 supported with JDK 7 or 8

Tags: java, jboss, java-7

I am trying to do Jboss eap7.0 setup in my system, when starting the server  getting error

```
"MAJOR.MINOR VERSION 52.0"
```

My code build with jdk 7, is this error because of jdk compactability or any other configuration issue. please help

Comment: There is a minor version mismatch. you must have build the code on JDK7 Update greater than 52 but are trying to run in JRE 7 update 52. So it is showing this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss EAP 7.0 supports:

Java Virtual Machine    Version

OpenJDK                  1.8  (Red Hat limits support of OpenJDK to Red Hat Enterprise Linux.)

Oracle JDK               1.8

IBM JDK                  1.8

HP JDK                   1.8 (Support for the HP JDK 1.8 was added with EAP version 7.0)

Azul Zing JDK            1.8

Azul Zulu                1.8

Comment: How about Amazon Correto 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

```
52.0
```

just means you have to upgrade to java SE 8

Answer (score 0):

***For future visitors:***

Refer to [this article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2026253).

Even better - I would say best is to Google this search string "Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP) 7 Supported Configurations" so that you would get the latest article